# How to specify a simple model in lmer/lme4: do I need explicit nesting?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, nested-data

I am measuring response time `RT_log` for 3 experimental manipulations (`Conditions`), and there are 4 `Ways` to achieve each `Condition`.  I would like to model `Condition` as a fixed effect, and `Way` as a random effect. The `Ways` are coded 1 to 12 (4 per `Condition`). I.e., there are 12 different `Ways`, but only 4 are applicable to each of the 3 `Conditions`. Is the following `lmer()` syntax correct for the experimental design and variable coding I have described?

`RT_log ~ Condition + (1|Way)`

Or do I need to re-code my `Way` variable so it is coded 1 to 4, and explicitly nested within `Condition`, with `lmer()` syntax as follows?

`RT_log ~ Condition + (1|Condition:Way)`